# MS SQL Collation Conflict Latin1_General_CI_AS Linked Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, collation

So i did some reading before posting this and was able to resolve most of the collation conflicts on most of the jobs that failed, but this last query is 1 step out of 3 in an agent job; I was able to resolve the other 2 by adding the COLLATE clause on the Joins.

On this query, it's saying the conflict is on the INSERT statement, but i understand the actual conflict could be any of the columns in the Select statement...

This new linked server was recently migrated and i wasn't brought in the loop so they didn't bother checking for compatibility issues...or testing anything really...

COMPANY_SQL01 is the linked server, SQL Server 2014

Company_BRK is the main server where this agent job step runs on, running SQL 2008, but compatability is set to SQL 2000(80)...

Before trying to troubleshoot individual queries, i went into the linked server and changed all the Databased to the SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS Collation, there's only individual columns that might still be on Latin1_General_CI_AS...

I get this error from the query below:
Msg 468, Level 16, State 9, Line 8
Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and "Latin1_General_CI_AS" in the equal to operation.

```
set transaction isolation level read uncommitted

declare @current as datetime = getdate()

delete from COMPANY_brk.dbo.COMPANY_ar_avg_days


insert into COMPANY_brk.dbo.COMPANY_ar_avg_days

select distinct cmp_id, sum(datediff(day, invdate, paydate))/count(invoicenum) 'avg_days'
from (
select dat_arobp.IDCUST as cmp_id,
CAST(SUBSTRING(CAST(dat_arobp.DATEBTCH AS CHAR(8)), 1, 4) 
                      + '-' + SUBSTRING(CAST(dat_arobp.DATEBTCH AS CHAR(8)), 5, 2) + '-' + SUBSTRING(CAST(dat_arobp.DATEBTCH AS CHAR(8)), 7, 2) AS smalldatetime) 
                      AS 'paydate', 
COMPANY_brk.dbo.invoiceheader.IVH_DELIVERYDATE AS 'invdate',
dat_arobl.IDINVC 'invoicenum'
from [COMPANY-SQL01].COMPANYdat.dbo.AROBL dat_arobl
inner join COMPANY_brk.dbo.invoiceheader on COMPANY_brk.dbo.invoiceheader.ivh_invoicenumber=dat_arobl.IDINVC
inner join [COMPANY-SQL01].COMPANYdat.dbo.AROBP dat_arobp on dat_arobp.IDMEMOXREF=COMPANY_brk.dbo.invoiceheader.ivh_invoicenumber
where dat_arobl.amtduetc=0 --and dat_arobp.DATERMIT<>'0'
and dat_arobp.IDINVC not in (select i.ivh_invoicenumber from COMPANY_brk.dbo.invoiceheader i)
and datediff(day, COMPANY_brk.dbo.invoiceheader.IVH_DELIVERYDATE, @current)<700
union
select usa_arobp.IDCUST as cmp_id,
CAST(SUBSTRING(CAST(usa_arobp.DATEBTCH AS CHAR(8)), 1, 4) 
                      + '-' + SUBSTRING(CAST(usa_arobp.DATEBTCH AS CHAR(8)), 5, 2) + '-' + SUBSTRING(CAST(usa_arobp.DATEBTCH AS CHAR(8)), 7, 2) AS smalldatetime) 
                      AS 'paydate', 
COMPANY_brk.dbo.invoiceheader.IVH_DELIVERYDATE AS 'invdate',
usa_arobl.IDINVC 'invoicenum'
from [COMPANY-SQL01].COMPANYusa.dbo.AROBL usa_arobl
inner join COMPANY_brk.dbo.invoiceheader on COMPANY_brk.dbo.invoiceheader.ivh_invoicenumber=usa_arobl.IDINVC
inner join [COMPANY-SQL01].COMPANYusa.dbo.AROBP usa_arobp on usa_arobp.IDMEMOXREF=COMPANY_brk.dbo.invoiceheader.ivh_invoicenumber
where usa_arobl.amtduetc=0 --and usa_arobp.DATERMIT<>'0'
and usa_arobp.IDINVC not in (select i.ivh_invoicenumber from COMPANY_brk.dbo.invoiceheader i)
and datediff(day, COMPANY_brk.dbo.invoiceheader.IVH_DELIVERYDATE, @current)<700
) as tbl
group by cmp_id
```

Comment: Since you are dealing with SQL 2000 (no longer supported) - why not do some data/database replication?  I know it is not an easy answer, as you are probably going to be fighting with a number of issues being that this is just the start or tip of the iceberg.

Comment: If it makes any difference, it's actually a 2008 R2 instance, but compatability is set to SQL 2000 (80).  Do you have any links i could look at regarding your suggestion?

Comment: A collation error happens any time two string columns are compared, or one is inserted into another. So simply look at all the string columns touched in the query to see what's what, and add an appropriate COLLATE clause to cast it to a different collation. You can start with SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE COLLATION_NAME IS NOT NULL ORDER BY TABLE_NAME, ORDINAL_POSITION

Comment: So i was able to confirm that the only places where a string is compared from 1 DB to the other are in the 2 Joins in each select statement and 1 in each WHERE clause, everything else seems to only be Dates so collate would not work for those... the query is taking forever to finish though...had to cancel it....Still no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Got this working today!

In the inner joins from both select statements,  i had to add COLLATE SQL_Latin1_Gerenal_CI_AS for the joins where comparing the main server to the link server and added COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS for the linked server>Main server comparisons:

```
inner join company_brk.dbo.invoiceheader on 
company_brk.dbo.invoiceheader.ivh_invoicenumber=dat_arobl.IDINVC COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

inner join [company-SQL01].flsdat.dbo.AROBP dat_arobp on 
dat_arobp.IDMEMOXREF=company_brk.dbo.invoiceheader.ivh_invoicenumber COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS
```

Also had to add 1 in the where clause:

```
and dat_arobp.IDINC COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT NOT IN (select ... )
```

The query is super slow and takes about 8minutes to update ~2k rows....But it's been like that since forever so if it's not broke...

/EDIT: So, the query works fine if i run it as is, but if try running the agent job, this same query ( Step 2 of 3) is creating a LCK_M_U on itself and it doesn't release it even after 20 minutes...still not fully resolved.